# Data table in screen flow salseforce

Tags: datatable, screen-flow

I added data table to my screen flow, and when I have one item the selected icon look like a radio button , I want that it will be like a check box, how to do that?

(The flow called from button on related list, and the content of the data table is the selected items)

Thanks!

Comment: you mean you want the user to be able to select more than one value? or you want the selection to be only 1 value but instead of radio button you want a checkbox?

Comment: First thanks, I want to allow select more than one- with checkbox, but when there is one item in the data table, the view is like a radio button..

Comment: So you want to allow people to select more than one, but if the datatable contains only one value, you want it to show radio button instead of checkbox?

Comment: No, I want always show checkbox, but I don't know why, when there is one item in the data table- automatically its show with radio button.(I don't want radio button..)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the setting as it is built in standard component, however, if you wish to change it, then you can try deploying your own **lightning web component.**

However, before you start building one, it is good to check if it is really necessary to do so.

As, the current behaviour is already good, in general use radio button to indicate you can only pick one option and a checkbox to allow for multiple selections.

In this case, when there is only one record, the radio button restricts the user to select only and the user can also know that there is only one option to choose.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing this as well - the table does not allow users to de-select the record if only 1 record exists in the table, despite the table being configured as multi-select, which should provide the ability to deselect.

It's either a bug or a missing feature during beta. My guess (or hope) is that this will be resolved when it graduates from beta status.

In the meantime, some workarounds to emulate a "Clear selections" button:

1. Add checkbox screen component that - when checked and user clicks "next" - will clear the default selection of the table & bring the user back to the screen
2. Install [UnofficialSF's Data Table LWC](https://unofficialsf.com/datatable-lightning-web-component-for-flow-screens-2/). I haven't use it yet but I'm quite certain it will not have this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deselect a single row (or all rows for that matter):

- Check "Add search bar" in the data table control
- When viewing the table, search for a non-existing term
- Clear the search term and voila, the selection is cleared

Hopefully, this limitation as well as a few other will be addressed in the foreseeable future.